# Issue with replacing word

Tags: php, string, replace

I try to replace word based on word. This is what I tried:

```
<?php
$reject = "dan n bb galeri";
$rejectarray=explode(" ",$reject);
$text = "saya dan kamu ganti pin bb";
echo str_replace($rejectarray,"",$text); //saya kamu gati pi
?>
```

I think the result is `saya kamu ganti pin` , instead `saya kamu gati pi` .
How to make the result like `saya kamu ganti pin`?

Comment: it removes every occurrence of 'n' in your $reject string because 'n' is an element in $rejectarray.

Comment: Using `kakamumu` still results in `kamu`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try add spaces:

```
$reject = "dan n bb galeri";
$text   = "saya dan kamu ganti pin bb";

function addspaces($value)
{
    return " ".$value." ";
}

$rejectarray = array_map('addspaces', explode(" ", $reject) );
$text = addspaces( $text ); // " saya ... bb "
// and strip result with trim()
echo trim( str_replace($rejectarray, " ", $text) ); //replace with space " "
```

Result:

```
saya kamu ganti pin
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because your explode function split string to array and one element of array has value as 'n'

this value of array is replaced with "", so you are loosing 'n' from ganti and also prom 'pin'

This is what happening

```
$rejectarray=explode(" ",$reject);
```

returns

```
$rejectarray = array("dan", "n", "bb", "galeri");
```

To resolve this problem, you need to have array that contains this three values

```
 $rejectarray = array("dan", "bb", "galeri");
```

for this you should unset value using this

```
unset($rejectarray[1]);
```

then do

```
echo str_replace($rejectarray,"",$text);
```

and then you will achieve your result correctly

Comment: This answer is not common solution and works for only example above

Comment: @safarov yes, in other case my $text = "saya dan n kamu ganti pin bb"; how to make result = "saya kamu ganti pin" ?

Answer (score 1):

`$reject[1]='n';`

which is replced by ''(NULL VALUE).
so ganti turns gani and pn turns pi

Answer (score 1):

Use [**array_intersect**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and [**array_diff**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) functions:

```
$reject = "dan n bb galeri";
$rejectarray = explode(" ", $reject);

$text = "saya dan n kamu ganti pin bb";
$text_array = explode(" ", $text);

//Find common values
$common_values = array_intersect($rejectarray, $text_array);

//Clean out common words from text array
$new_text_array = array_diff($text_array, $common_values);

//Merge array values and from new text
echo implode(' ', $new_text_array);
```